# Customize balloon text in amCharts pie chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am generating a 3D Donut chart by using amCharts and I wanted to show the table in balloon text when rolled over on pie pieces as shown in the below specified link. I wanted to customize the table in balloon text which will only show row as per the number of items it contains and shouldn't show the any extra row lines.

http://codepen.io/PratikDJ/pen/WwOXmr

```
var balloonText = '<p style="font-size: 120%; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 15px;"></p>\
          <table>\
            <tr><th>People Name</th></tr>\
            <tr><td>[[people1]]</td></tr>\
            <tr><td>[[people2]]</td></tr>\
            <tr><td>[[people3]]</td></tr>\
            <tr><td>[[people4]]</td></tr>\
            <tr><td>[[people5]]</td></tr>\
            <tr><td>[[people6]]</td></tr>\
          </table>';
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "titles": [ {
    "text": "",
    "size": 16
  } ],
  "dataProvider": [
    {
        "Status": "alive",
        "NoOPeople": 5,
        "people1": "ajith",
        "people2": "rahul",
        "people3": "gaurav",
        "people4": "abhay",
        "people5": "ganesh",
        "people6": "gopi"
    },
    {
        "Status": "dead",
        "NoOPeople": 3,
        "people1": "suraj",
        "people2": "chethan",
        "people3": "subhash"
    }
],
  "valueField": "NoOPeople",
  "titleField": "Status",
  "startEffect": "elastic",
  "startDuration": 2,
  "labelRadius": 15,
  "innerRadius": "50%",
  "depth3D": 10,
  "balloonText": balloonText,
  "angle": 15,
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );
jQuery( '.chart-input' ).off().on( 'input change', function() {
  var property = jQuery( this ).data( 'property' );
  var target = chart;
  var value = Number( this.value );
  chart.startDuration = 0;

  if ( property == 'innerRadius' ) {
    value += "%";
  }

  target[ property ] = value;
  chart.validateNow();
} );
```

In the above link I have prepared a sample which contains dead people 3 and alive 6, in this whenever I rollover on the dead status (yellow color pie) it shows the name of the people who are dead and as the dead people are less then alive it shows 3 empty row which does not look good.

Can you help me show only number of rows according to the number of items.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`balloonFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#balloonFunction) for that. You can set it to a custom function that will take the slice data and format contents of the balloon.

```
"balloonFunction": function( item, content ) {
  var html = '<p style="font-size: 120%; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 15px;"></p>\
    <table>\
    <tr><th>People Name</th></tr>';
  for ( var x in item.dataContext ) {
    if ( item.dataContext.hasOwnProperty( x ) && x.match( /^people/ ) ) {
      html += '<tr><td>' + item.dataContext[ x ] + '</td></tr>';
    }
  }
  html += '</table>';
  return html;
}
```

Here's the [updated demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/a7d1c4e6a6232f7406ac9df47d368554/).